# Expose Active Directory to the Internet

Tags: active-directory

I need to find how can I expose Active Directory on my Widnows 2003 server to the internet. I need to be able to make Active Directory avaliable to my development computer.

The Active Directory is installed on a Windows 2003 VPS.

Comment: Making AD wide open would not be a very good idea.  EK's suggestion of VPN is the way to go.

Comment: Although this is not a good idea - it's a good question to ask and be answered as this is what "newbies" can do wrong!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Setup a vpn to connect your development computer to the domain network.  That way you do not need to expose your network.

Answer (score 0):

One other convoluted way would be to use IPSec to allow connections from AD to your computer, but secured with IPSec. I have tested it with HTTP and file serving in the lab a couple of times, but of course AD needs a pile of ports. Kinda a point-to-point VPN.